# Advanced VIM Replacement to Generate C# codes

Tags: c#, vim

I like to use VIM to quickly generate snip of codes from text. Now I have case I think I may need to use VIM advanced find & replacement to convert text to a snip of codes. The following text is a simplified example:

```
value1
value2
...
valueN
```

I use VIM vertical block to insert prefix string, or use find & replace (:%s/^/public const string /") to achieve the same result like this:

```
public const string value1
public const string value2
...
public const string valueN
```

Now I would like to complete the above text to codes like this:

```
public const string value1 = "value1";
public const string value2 = "value2";
...
public const string valueN = "valueN";
```

Note: the value1..valueN are simplified ones, they are actually in various length.  Not sure if there is any way to use VIM advanced find & replace to add the suffix string with the last word as reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your initial list:

```
 :%s/\(.*\)/public const string \1 = "\1";
```

Should do it.

Comment: To be clear, this example starts from the original list, not the list after the vertical block is used to add the "public const string" prefixes. If you want the latter, use `:%s/public const string (.*)/public const string \1 = "\1"`

Comment: Thanks @Chris, yes, as I said "from your initial list". Your example is just missing the backslashes on the parentheses.

Comment: I like your solution even there are other simple ones just for my case. However, I would like to learn more about VIM and its find/replace power feature. I think this one may be used to resolve my second case (with prefix "private const..."): %s/\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\1 "\2";/  Here \1 and \2 are matched group names. It works fine. Is there any better way?

Comment: Hey @David, The regular expression engine in Vim is quite powerful. Your example is missing escape in the parentheses, and also an equal. Other than that, yes it works. There are many ways to do it. Your way fails if there is whitespace before the new line (give it a try and understand why). A safer way would be changing the last .* by a character class. Regex is quite powerful and present in many places, so it's really important (and useful!) for a programer to have a certain knowledge on it. I can recomend you the book 'mastering regular expressions', if you're looking for a place to start.

Answer (score 4):

To complete the above answer:

```
:%s/.*/public const string & = "&";
```

will work too. I recently discovered that & means the whole matched pattern.
For advanced regexp, you could should give a look at the help.

```
:h regexp
```

There is crazy but useful stuff!

Since I am new I can't add a comment to the answer above... Sorry

Comment: The parenthesis capturing is redundant in this case: `:%s/.*/public const string & = "&";/`.

Comment: Nice catch! Copy paste too late in the day are harmful... Thanks for the fix. (edited above answer)

Comment: +1, Thanks for the `&` tip Plouff, indeed I knew about it but somehow didn't include this in my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. But I agree that for complex regexps, \n are more versatile.